# throwable anonymous closure in swift

Tags: swift, throw, throwable

I have this piece of code, but I would like to improve it a bit by making it more "functional"

```
var person = Person.getOne(on: db, with: ["name": name])
if person == nil {
    let personId = try Person.insert(on: db, with: ["name": name])
    person = Person.getOne(on: db, withIdentifier: personId)
}
```

So I did :

```
let harbor = Harbor.getOne(on: db, with: ["name": formattedName]) ?? {
    let harborId = try Harbor.insert(on: db, with: ["name": formattedName])
    return Harbor.getOne(on: db, withIdentifier: harborId)
}()
```

It would work perfectly without `try`ing to insert. So I have to mark my anonymous closure to `throws` and `try` to execute it.

Is it possible do achieve this in swift?

Comment: Only functions, methods, or initializers can `throw`

Comment: You can just say `let harbor = try Harbor.getOne...`

Comment: oh @hamish, it seems that you're right! I tryied to place the `try` just after the `??`, but it did not work. Placing it before the `getOne` (which do not throws) resolves the problem.

Comment: How about you use `try!` instead of `try` but this could cause a crash if somehow the value resulted to `nil` which is really not recommended

Comment: `try!` is a bad option because 1/ it forces unwrap, and 2/ it prevent from handling the error

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @hamish, the solution was to add a `try` before the entire expression:

```
let harbor = try Harbor.getOne(on: db, with: ["name": formattedName]) ?? {
    let harborId = try Harbor.insert(on: db, with: ["name": formattedName])
    return Harbor.getOne(on: db, withIdentifier: harborId)
}()
```

It seems strange because the first `getOne` do not `throws` any error.